# How to replace spaces after a certain pattern with commas?

Tags: regex, shell, sed, bioinformatics

I am new to coding and I'm trying to format some bioinformatics data. I am trying to remove all the spaces after `GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV` with commas, but not anything outside of the format `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` (like the example). I know I need to use `sed` with regex option but I'm not very familiar with how to use it. I've never actually used `sed` before and got confused trying so any help would be appreciated. Sorry if I formatted this poorly (this is my first post).

EDIT 2: I got actual data from the file this time which may help solve the problem. Removed the bad example.

New Example: I pulled this data from my actual file (this is just two samples), and it is surrounded by other data. Essentially the line has a bunch of data followed by "GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV ", after this there is more data in the format shown below, and finally there is some more random data. Unfortunately I can't post a full line of the data because it is extremely long and will not fit.

Input

```
0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0 0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0
```

Output

```
0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0
```

Comment: Looks very much like a vcf format, how did you end up with this format? Maybe if you explain previous steps then we wouldn't have this problem?

Comment: @zx8754 I'm using Fast-GBS to generate vcf files and then filtering them using a script written by the last bioinformatician who worked here (and this generates a text file that I view in excel). However I need to use a delimited for text-> columns and I don't want it to split up the last column of the file generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Basic Regular Expressions, you can use *character classes* and *backreferences* to accomplish your task, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*\)[ ]\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*\)/\1,\2/g' file
1/0 ./. 0/1 GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV 1:12:314,213:132:13:31,14:31:31 AB GT BB
1/0 ./. 0/1 GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV 10:13:12,41:41:1:13,13:131:1:1 AB GT RT
1/0 ./. 0/1 GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV 1:12:314,213:132:13:31,14:31:31 AB GT
```

Which basically says:

- find and capture any `[0-9][0-9]*` one or more digits,
- separated by a `:`, and
- followed by `[0-9][0-9]*` one or more digits -- as capture group 1,
- match a space following capture group 1 followed by capture group 2 (which is the same as capture group 1),
- then replace the space separating the capture groups with a comma reinserting the capture group text using backreference 1 and 2 (e.g. `\1` and `\2`), finally
- make the replacement *global* (e.g. `g`) to replace all matching occurrences.

**Edit Based On New Input Posted**

If you still need all of the original commas added, **and** you now want to add a comma between `,0 0/` (where there is a comma precedes a single-digit followed by the space to be replaced with a comma, followed by a single-digit and a forward-slash), then all you need to do is make your capture groups conditional (on either capturing the original data as above -or- capturing this new segment. You do that by including an OR (e.g. `\|` in basic regex terms) between the conditions.

For instance by adding `\|,[0-9]` at the end of the first capture group and `\|[0-9][/]` at the end of the second, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*\|,[0-9]\)[ ]\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]*\|[0-9][/]\)/\1,\2/g' file
0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0
```

If you have other caveats in your file, I suggest you post several complete lines of input, and if they are too long, then create a zip, gzip, bzip or xz file and post it to a site like pastebin and add the link to your question.

If all you really care about now is the space in `,0 0/`, then you can shorten the `sed` command to:

```
$ sed 's/\(,[0-9]\)[[:space:]]\([0-9][/]\)/\1,\2/g' file
0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0
```

(**note:** I've included `[[:space:]]` to handle any whitespace (space, tab, ...) instead of just the literal `[ ]` (space) in the new example)
Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome explanation. Thanks, for the response, I'll give this a try as well tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. If you have extended regular expressions, they can shorten the command a bit, but some systems do not support them. You can always use basic regular expressions -- even if it takes a few more keystrokes. Good to know both. Also note, if you want to match any whitespace between the capture groups, you can replace `[ ]` with `\s`.

Comment: Only some seds would recognize `\s` as shorthand for `[[:space:]]`. GNU sed would, idk about others.

Comment: Good point. (I was stuck taking the survey -- get a cup of coffee and comfortable slippers on first...)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I think I didn't provide a good example of the data and that may have given the wrong idea. I pulled this data from my actual file (this is just two samples), and it is surrounded by other data. Essentially the line has a bunch of data followed by `GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV `, after this there is more data in the format shown below, and finally there is some more random data.  
Input  

`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0 0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`  


Output  



`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`

Comment: Please post a complete line from your example data. It is impossible to provide a confirmed solution when presented with only partial data. I suspect you have additional colon separated numbers in the line which will present problems.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I can't post an entire line as the line is extremely long (approximately 400 columns/samples) with a lot of variants. There are no additional colons in the line at all, aside from the section after `GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV ` which has the data that needs commas in between them (rather than spaces). I added an example to the post showing what two full samples of data look like that need to be separated by a comma rather than a space (straight from the file).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much, worked flawlessly!!

Comment: Glad it helped. It's worth making friends with `sed`. It's cryptic as hell at first, but take building regular expressions the same way you eat a whale (one bite at a time), and in a very short period, you can become quite fluent with it. Also make friends with `awk` (same cryptic analogy), but with both in your toolbox, there are very few text processing problems you can't solve.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the `xx:xx:xx` or `xx:xx:xx:xx` can have any number of parts, since some have 3, and some have 4.

This is quite difficult to do reliably with `sed`, as it does not support lookarounds, which seem like they might be needed for this example.

You can try something like:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d) (?=\d+(:\d+){2,})/,/g' input.txt
```

If you've got your heart set on `sed`, you can try this, but it may miss some cases:

```
sed -r 's/(:[0-9]+) ([0-9]+:)/\1,\2/g' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try tomorrow when I am back at my work computer and see if it works. I'm not super set on `sed` but when I was searching online I found more example of sed being used for similar scenarios. Also (just out of curiousity so I can learn) is it possible to use `sed -e` with the format I indicated?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem at all. You can also pipe in/out of the sed command, if you wanted.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I think I didn't provide a good example of the data and that may have given the wrong idea. I pulled this data from my actual file (this is just two samples), and it is surrounded by other data. Essentially the line has a bunch of data followed by `GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV `, after this there is more data in the format shown below, and finally there is some more random data.  
Input  

`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0 0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`  


Output  



`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`

Answer (score 0):

You may also achieve your desired result without regex, using awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $1FS$2FS$3FS$4FS$5","$6","$7; for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", FS$i; print ""}' input.txt
```

Basically, it outputs from field 1 to 5 with the default field separator ("space"), then from field 5 to 7 with the comma separator, then from field 8 onwards with default separator again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll take this into consideration, but I'm not sure this will work as the number of fields that would require the comma separator can potentially vary depending on the data, and same with the fields afterwards. But thanks, I learned something new :)

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for mentioning the pitfalls of misusing `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. This will take care of printing those values also which are NOT coming in match of regex. Also we would have made regex mentioned in match a bit shorter by doing it as `[0-9]+\.{4}` etc since this is tested on old awk so couldn't test it.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
match($0,/GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART!=1?1:RSTART,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
  value1=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",",value1)
  print value,value1
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I think I didn't provide a good example of the data and that may have given the wrong idea. I pulled this data from my actual file (this is just two samples), and it is surrounded by other data. Essentially the line has a bunch of data followed by `GT:GL:GOF:GQ:NR:NV `, after this there is more data in the format shown below, and finally there is some more random data.  

>Input  

`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0 0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`  


>Output  



`0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0`

Answer (score 0):

> perl myscript.pl '0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0 0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0'

myscript.pl,

```
  #!/usr/local/ActivePerl-5.20/bin/env perl
    my $input = $ARGV[0];
    $input =~ s/ /\,/g; 
    print $input, "\n";
__DATA__
```

**output**

0/1:-1,-1,-1:146:28:14,14:4,0,0/1:-1,-1,-1:134:6:2,2:1,0

This will remove all spaces, not just the space in question